# How do you query a main table with known duplicates that also have tags?

Tags: sql, mysql, join, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have a main table called `pics` that has an ID number and the origin site from which it was pulled from. I also have another table called `tags` that has a list of all the tags that were also pulled from that site. Here's the kicker, there are known duplicates. The way in which duplicates are known is irrelevant. The `duplicates` are also stored in their own table. The first column, "original", is the first instance of it in the "pics" table. The second column is any `additional` duplicate. The website searches images based on tags, which can be more than one tag.
*(I know having the source site in the `pics` table may not be optimal, nor proper database design.)* **This must work on MySQL/phpMyAdmin.**

[image]

**1. What is the SQL join query that will list all of the image ID numbers when searching for a specific tag? For example:**

- Search String: `fire`, Result: `[null]`
- Search String: `red`, Result: `#1`
- Search String: `vines`, Result: `#2`
- Search String: `green`, Result: `#2`
- Search String: `forest brown`, Result: `#2`
- Search String: `bird tree`, Result: `[null]`

**2. What is the SQL join query that will merge the image source sites? For example:**

- Site(s) for image: `1`, Result: `colors.com`
- Site(s) for image: `2`, Result: `colors.com` `nature.com`
- Site(s) for image: `4`, Result: `nature.com`
- (Getting the sites for #5 and #6 doesn't matter because they would always reference #2 anyway.)

**3. OR would it honestly just be easier to not do this complicated join stuff and do simpler join queries and have an automated, scheduled procedure manually merge tags and delete duplicate entries?**

Here is the SQL to copy paste into a blank database:

```
START TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE `duplicates` (`original` int(2) NOT NULL,`additional` int(2) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO `duplicates` (`original`, `additional`) VALUES (2, 5),(2, 6);
CREATE TABLE `pics` (`id` int(2) NOT NULL,`sourceSite` text NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO `pics` (`id`, `sourceSite`) VALUES (1, 'colors.com'),(2, 'colors.com'),(3, 'colors.com'),(4, 'nature.com'),(5, 'nature.com'),(6, 'nature.com');
CREATE TABLE `tags` (`id` int(2) NOT NULL,`tag` varchar(16) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO `tags` (`id`, `tag`) VALUES (1, 'red'),(1, 'orange'),(2, 'green'),(2, 'brown'),(3, 'blue'),(3, 'cyan'),(4, 'bird'),(4, 'flight'),(5, 'tree'),(5, 'forest'),(6, 'vines'),(6, 'tree');
ALTER TABLE `duplicates` ADD KEY `original` (`original`), ADD KEY `additional` (`additional`);
ALTER TABLE `pics` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `tags` ADD KEY `id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `duplicates` ADD CONSTRAINT `duplicates_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`original`) REFERENCES `pics` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT `duplicates_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`additional`) REFERENCES `pics` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE `tags` ADD CONSTRAINT `tags_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `pics` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: This was tricky to articulate for me, so please have patience.

Comment: "Search String: forest brown, Result: #2" - This is because both the tags point to the same pic. "Search String: bird tree, Result: [null]" - Why is this? Is it because both point to different pics? 'bird' = 4, 'tree' = 5 -> 2. What should 'fire tree' return? 'fire' does not point to anything, 'tree' points to 5 and then using duplicates, goes to 2. So, should it return 2 (as there is only one id)? or nothing (since fire does not give anything)?

Comment: @Surgemus Neither of the queries provided in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77125976) function correctly - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5_of8JLz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this with your current structure is very inefficient but can be done.

It is important to note that, as your `duplicates` table is a junction table, it should be indexed in both directions with composite indices:

```
CREATE TABLE `duplicates` (
    `original` INT NOT NULL,
    `additional` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`original`, `additional`),
    INDEX (`additional`, `original`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`original`) REFERENCES `pics` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`additional`) REFERENCES `pics` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Searching the pic IDs based on a set of tags:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(d.original, t.id) AS id
FROM tags t
LEFT JOIN duplicates d ON d.additional = t.id
WHERE t.tag IN ('forest', 'brown', 'vines')
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.tag) = 3 -- because we have 3 tags to find
```

Searching for sources of a given pic ID:

```sql
SELECT p.sourceSite
FROM pics p
WHERE p.id = 2
UNION
SELECT p.sourceSite
FROM pics p
JOIN duplicates d ON d.additional = p.id
WHERE d.original = 2;
```

If you want to tie both of the above together so you can search for pics based on a set of tags and return the id, sources and full list of tags you can do the following.

**First step**: get the ids of the images with all of the required tags:

```sql
WITH pics_by_tags (pic_id) AS (
    SELECT COALESCE(d.original, t.id)
    FROM tags t
    LEFT JOIN duplicates d ON d.additional = t.id
    WHERE t.tag IN ('forest', 'brown', 'vines')
    GROUP BY 1
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.tag) = 3 -- because we have 3 tags to find
)
SELECT * FROM pics_by_tags;
```

Output:

| pic_id |
| --- |
| 2 |

**Second step**: get sources for each of the pics returned in previous step:

```sql
WITH pics_by_tags (pic_id) AS (
    /* as before */
),
pics_with_sites (pic_id, sites) AS (
    SELECT pbt.pic_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.sourceSite)
    FROM pics_by_tags pbt
    JOIN pics p
        ON pbt.pic_id = p.id
        OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM duplicates d WHERE pbt.pic_id = d.original AND p.ID = d.additional)
    GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT * FROM pics_with_sites;
```

Output:

| pic_id | sites |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | colors.com,nature.com |

**Third step**: get full list of tags for result of previous step:

```sql
WITH pics_by_tags (pic_id) AS (
    /* as before */
),
pics_with_sites (pic_id, sites) AS (
    /* as before */
)
SELECT p.pic_id, p.sites, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tag ORDER BY t.tag) AS tags
FROM pics_with_sites p
JOIN tags t
    ON p.pic_id = t.id
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM duplicates d WHERE p.pic_id = d.original AND t.id = d.additional)
GROUP BY p.pic_id, p.sites;
```

Output:

| pic_id | sites | tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | colors.com,nature.com | brown,forest,green,tree,vines |

The full query is:

```sql
WITH pics_by_tags (pic_id) AS (
    SELECT COALESCE(d.original, t.id)
    FROM tags t
    LEFT JOIN duplicates d ON d.additional = t.id
    WHERE t.tag IN ('forest', 'brown', 'vines')
    GROUP BY 1
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.tag) = 3 -- because we have 3 tags to find
),
pics_with_sites (pic_id, sites) AS (
    SELECT pbt.pic_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.sourceSite)
    FROM pics_by_tags pbt
    JOIN pics p
        ON pbt.pic_id = p.ID
        OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM duplicates d WHERE pbt.pic_id = d.original AND p.id = d.additional)
    GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT p.pic_id, p.sites, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tag ORDER BY t.tag) AS tags
FROM pics_with_sites p
JOIN tags t
    ON p.pic_id = t.id
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM duplicates d WHERE p.pic_id = d.original AND t.id = d.additional)
GROUP BY p.pic_id, p.sites;
```

---

Obviously, this task would be much better served by a normalized structure, without the duplication.

Something like:

```
pictures (id, other_picture_meta_data)
sources (id, name)
tags_new (id, name)
pics_sources (pic_id, source_id)
pics_tags (pic_id, tag_id)
```

With the revised structure the query becomes:

```sql
WITH pics_by_tags (pic_id) AS (
    SELECT pt.pic_id
    FROM tags_new tn
    JOIN pics_tags pt ON tn.id = pt.tag_id
    WHERE tn.name IN ('forest', 'brown', 'vines')
    GROUP BY 1
    HAVING COUNT(tn.name) = 3 -- because we have 3 tags to find
),
pics_with_sites (pic_id, sites) AS (
    SELECT pbt.pic_id, GROUP_CONCAT(s.name)
    FROM pics_by_tags pbt
    JOIN pics_sources ps ON pbt.pic_id = ps.pic_id
    JOIN sources s ON ps.source_id = s.id
    GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT p.*, pws.sites, GROUP_CONCAT(tn.name ORDER BY tn.name) AS tags
FROM pics_with_sites pws
JOIN pictures p ON pws.pic_id = p.id
JOIN pics_tags pt ON pws.pic_id = pt.pic_id
JOIN tags_new tn ON pt.tag_id = tn.id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zXdqXWf2) to play with.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a graphic representation of your schema. Let's work with this.

[image]

1. SQL query to list images under a given tag:

   ```sql
   SELECT pics.*
   FROM tags
       LEFT JOIN duplicates ON tags.id = duplicates.original OR tags.id = duplicates.additional
       LEFT JOIN pics on duplicates.original = pics.id
   WHERE tags.tag = "green"
   GROUP BY duplicates.original;
   ```

   That is, given an input tag, e.g. `green`:

   1. query for tags whose `tags.tag` equal `"green"`,
   2. pull up any `duplicates` that are related by `tags.id`,
   3. "squash" these duplicates into one by grouping them by `duplicates.original`, so that only one duplicate "prevails", then
   4. get the corresponding `pics.*` based on the result above.

   In hindsight, you might want to consider creating foreign key constraints between tables `tags` and `duplicates`.
2. SQL query to list source sites of images:

   ```sql
   SELECT pics.sourceSite
   FROM duplicates
       LEFT JOIN pics ON duplicates.additional = pics.id
   WHERE duplicates.original = 2 OR duplicates.additional = 2
   GROUP BY pics.sourceSite
   ```

   That is, given an input image ID, e.g. `2`:

   1. look up for `duplicates` that references the image ID `2`,
   2. query `pics` associated to any duplicates in the result above, then
   3. group by and select the source sites of these pictures.
3. Ideally, you want to prune duplicates and normalize tags. But in reality, there might be valid factors for not doing so. In short, *it depends*.™

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `FULLTEXT` index on a column that contains all the tags for the matching image.

Then this would catch #5 and #6, ordering #5 first due to more 'relevance':

```
MATCH(tags) AGAINST ("forest tree" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

whereas  this would catch only #5:

```
MATCH(tags) AGAINST ("+forest +tree" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```